SDL2, Event poll confusion
I don't know whether i am right or wrong but according to what i know at time of execution of program of sdl2 the event queue is empty at start and so the inner loop should not get executed and flag should remain 0 and window should show up till system crash or program terminated then why window is getting closed immediately after opening ?? code is attached below
bool looper = true;
int flag = 0;
while (looper)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        // any event
        flag = 1;
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_0)
                looper = false;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        looper = false;
}

Make me enlightened why my assumptions are wrong?

no, the queue is not empty, you opened a window, opening the window will send you an event, actually not one event but a ton of events, then the OS will try to draw the window on the screen, that's a lot more events., use SDL_Log("event") to see how many events you would get just by opening a window, event are not only keyboard events, there are a ton of events that get sent to your application each second, you even get sent "idle" events every now and then

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Add a breakpoint inside the event loop would allow you to know which event you have.
